# Where clause in MySQL stored procedure not working

Tags: mysql

Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure sp_vehicleinformation_update(in vehiclemake nvarchar(50),
                                in vehiclemodel nvarchar(50),in deviceid nvarchar(50))
begin
       update device set vehicleMake=vehiclemake,vehicleModel=vehiclemodel       
       where deviceID=deviceid;
end $$
$$
```

**N:B:** I am using MySQL Workbench to write MySQL code.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Is there an error message, or does it just fail silently?